# (women's) formula?

Tags: meaning

A dialogue from a well-known sitcom:

> Joey - That eggnog in our fridge was great
> Rachel - Joey, that was formula

What kind of **formula** would that be? Cant find anything on wikipedia or search engines...

Comment: substitute milk for an infant

Comment: Try "baby formula".

Comment: Baby food with some sort of rich milk and vitamins is called formula. Joey is not smart enough to know that a baby in the house could mean baby food in the refrigerator.

Comment: Oh...must be what we call "farin lacte" here. Funny to be in the same place with Joey. Anyway, I guess you should formulate an answer...

Comment: It is not "farin lacte."  That would be "baby cereal."  I believe the Greek is Γάλα σε Σκόνη, although, it appears that term might be more general, referring to any powdered milk, like the kind we might use in baking bread.  I don't read Greek, but I think this is the right product: [Γιώτης Γάλα σε Σκόνη Sanilac HA](https://www.skroutz.gr/s/3246935/%CE%93%CE%B9%CF%8E%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82-%CE%93%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1-%CF%83%CE%B5-%CE%A3%CE%BA%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%B7-Sanilac-HA-0m-400gr.html)

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks, that must be it. The toughest English to learn are the everyday ones.